# Why go to file in WebStorm IDE is not working properly?

Tags: ide, webstorm

WebStorm is unable to locate a file. I hit <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd> and start typing file name, but no files found:

[image: WebStorm not found the file]

I have tried to invalidate and restart, also I have checked that folder is not marked as excluded, but no success - still can not navigate to case-request. I have checked that everything working. Tha only problem with folder at `App/case` the folder itself and everything under it is not searchable, however I still can open it manually from the source tree and edit. The app is a root for angularjs application.

[image]

Does anyone know what can be wrong? The same project opened in Visual Studio locates the file:

[image: Visual Studio locates the file]

Answer (score 2):

Please try invalidating caches (**File | Invalidate caches, Invalidate and restart**).
If the issue persists, make sure that the folder file resides in is not excluded from project (marked *Excluded*)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, I have tried it multiple times, it unable to locate only App/case folder and all the files under it. Currently continue using visual the studio for the project, it is rather good, I wanted to change smth for curiousity :)

Comment: I have checked that folder is not excluded, also I have updated the question with more details and what I have tried.

Comment: I have added answer with my current solution. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what wrong. Finally I have tried to app/case as separate content root, seems it is working.

Steps I followed:

1. Press ctrl + alt + s
2. Select directories if it is not selected at left pane
3. Exclude Case from project (right click on the case folder and select excluded)
4. Press "Add Content Root" at right pane
5. Select the case as content root
6. Remove excluded flag from case folder (right click on the case folder and select excluded)

After this the case folder became searchable. I have tried to remove content root but as result case again became not searchable.

I don't know if it can lead to any issues in future.

[image]